# bitbucket cloud - force Pull-Requests to be connected to JIRA issue

Tags: bitbucket, jira

I want to make sure each created/approved/merged PR is connected to a JIRA issue.

I currently can "Require issue keys in commit messages", but this forces each commit to have the JIRA issue in it. All I want is the PR (or the branch) to have it.

Is there another way to make sure no branches/Pull-requests are merged (or even created) without linking it to JIRA?